# Neo4j Condition Based Output

Tags: database, neo4j, addition, database-partitioning

Question:
In Neo4j, I have relation `(p:Person)-[:HAS_DOCUMNET]->(id:Identification)-[:HAS_DESCRIPTION]->(d:Document)` and Required only 1 row data per person (personId,documentType and idNumber)
I required to develop query output on the basis of below priority condition
1)If documentType="Passport" is present then should come with personId and respected idNumber.(1st Priority)
2)If documentType="VoterCard" is present then should come with personeId and respected idNumber.(If Passport is not present)
3)If documentType="PanCard" is present then should come withe personId and respected idNumber.(If VoterId is not present)

Data Present like below:

```
(P1:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->('id1','id2','id3')->[:HAS_DESCRIPTION]->("Passpot","VoterCard",PanCard)`
(P2:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->('id4','id5')->[:HAS_DESCRIPTION]->("VoterCard","PanCard")`
(P3:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->('id6','id7','id8')->[:HAS_DESCRIPTION]->("PanCard","AadharCard","VoterCard")
(P4:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->('id9')->[:HAS_DESCRIPTION]->("PanCard")
```

Output should be like :

```
PName    Doc.Type     IDNumber
-------  -----------  ---------
  P1      "Passport"    id1
  P2      "VoterCard"   id4
  P3      "VoterCard"   id8
  P4      "PanCard"     id9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created below sample data as you described.  The query involves a simple case when else and I collected the documents then check if passport, votercard and pancard exists in the collection.

```
(P1:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->("Passport","VoterCard","PanCard")
(P2:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->("VoterCard","PanCard")`
(P3:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->("PanCard","AadharCard","VoterCard")
(P4:Person)-[:HAS_Document]->("PanCard")

Create (p1:Person {Name: 'P1'})
Create (p2:Person {Name: 'P2'})
Create (p3:Person {Name: 'P3'})
Create (p4:Person {Name: 'P4'})
Create (d1:Document {Doc_Type: 'Passport'})
Create (d2:Document {Doc_Type: 'VoterCard'})
Create (d3:Document {Doc_Type: 'PanCard'})
Create (d4:Document {Doc_Type: 'AadharCard'})
Merge (p1)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d1)
Merge (p1)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d2)
Merge (p1)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d3)
Merge (p2)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d2)
Merge (p2)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d3)
Merge (p3)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d3)
Merge (p3)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d4)
Merge (p3)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d2)
Merge (p4)-[:HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d3)

Query:
    MATCH (p: Person)-[: HAS_DOCUMENT]-(d:Document) 
    WHERE d.Doc_Type in ["Passport", "VoterCard", "PanCard"]
    WITH p.Name as Name, collect(d.Doc_Type) as docType
    RETURN Name, 
    CASE WHEN 'Passport' in docType THEN 'Passport'
     WHEN 'VoterCard' in docType THEN 'VoterCard'
     WHEN  'PanCard' in docType THEN 'PanCard' 
    ELSE NULL END as DocType
    ORDER BY Name

Result:
╒══════╤═══════════╕
│"Name"│"DocType"  │
╞══════╪═══════════╡
│"P1"  │"Passport" │
├──────┼───────────┤
│"P2"  │"VoterCard"│
├──────┼───────────┤
│"P3"  │"VoterCard"│
├──────┼───────────┤
│"P4"  │"PanCard"  │
└──────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ for my previous question, It was working as expected and i have added one more node and complexity on my previous question, can you please help me with that ?